# Get all records in cakephp3 using TableRegistry?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

My Demo Controller (DemoController.php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;
class DemoController extends AppController
    {
       public function users()
        {
            $this->loadmodel('registration');
            $result = $this->registration->getAllUsers();
            $this->set('user_data',$result)
        }
    }
?>
```

My registration model (registration.php):

```
<?php
namespace App\Model;

use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class Registration extends AppModel {

    $articles = TableRegistry::get('registration');

    public function getAllUsers()
        {
            return $query = $articles->find();
        }

}
?>
```

My View:

```
path -- src/Template/Demo/users.ctp
```

but it's getting error like this (in below image) --

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your model should be named `RegistrationsTable`, and be in `src/Model/Table/RegistrationsTable.php`. Load it with `loadModel('Registrations')`. (It's your *entity* that should be named `Registration`.) To use your [custom finder method](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods), name the function findAllUsers, fix the signature per the documentation (should take two parameters: `Query $query, array $options`) and call it as `$this->Registration->find('all_users');`.

And why are you trying to initialize a `$articles` variable as the registrations model inside the registrations model (but outside of any function)? So much mess...